# How to replace all frames of video to one image?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have some film
I want to replace all frames from that video to my static image.
So that video duration, resolution(width, height), sound and other properties stay the same.

Comment: Is the new image of the same resolution?

Comment: Yes, we could  just scale to needed resolution

Comment: you can use "-c:a copy" to copy the audio...in terms of getting resolution to stay the same, the only way I know of is to parse the output of `ffmpeg -i xxx` and determine resolution there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i image
  -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][v];[v][i]overlay" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The scale2ref filter resizes the image to the same size as the video. The overlay filter then superimposes the images onto the video, repeating it till it ends.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.